# NSOutputStream outputStreamToBuffer not compliant with docs?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a network based iOS app, using Test Driven Development. Now I've hit a snag when testing the methods to write to the output stream. I need my tests to verify that an incomplete write is resumed at the next `NSStreamHasSpaceAvailable` event. I figured that using `[NSOutputStream outputStreamToBuffer: capacity:]` would be appropriate when setting a capacity lower than the length of the data being written.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states:

> When the number of bytes written to buffer has reached capacity, the stream’s streamStatus will return NSStreamStatusAtEnd.

However, this is not what I'm experiencing. When I attempt a write that exceeds the capacity of the stream, the return value of `write` is `-1`, and the stream is put in an error state (`NSStreamStatusError`). Printing `streamError` gives the following error:

```
Stream error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=12 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Cannot allocate memory"
```

If I limit the attempted write to match the stream capacity, the write itself works as expected, but the `streamStatus` still returns `NSStreamStatusOpen` rather than `NSStreamStatusAtEnd`.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug? I have only tried it in the simulator so far (OS X 10.9, Xcode 5.0.2, iOS 7 simulator).

Sample code to reproduce:

```
- (void)testOutputStreamStuff
{
    uint8_t buf[10];
    NSOutputStream *stream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToBuffer:buf capacity:10];
    [stream open];
    NSLog(@"Stream status: %u", [stream streamStatus]);
    NSData *data = [@"Just creating some data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSUInteger bytesWritten = [stream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    NSLog(@"Bytes written: %i", bytesWritten);
    NSLog(@"Stream error: %@", [stream streamError]);
    NSLog(@"Stream status: %u", [stream streamStatus]);
}
```

The output of the NSLog statements above is:

```
Stream status: 2
Bytes written: -1
Stream error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=12 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Cannot allocate memory"
Stream status: 7
```

As I understand from the documentation, the expected output should be:

```
Stream status: 2
Bytes written: 10
Stream error: (NULL)
Stream status: 5
```

Any help is appreciated! Even alternative ways to unit test an output stream, but I suppose that's a topic for a different question. :)

UPDATE: I tried it on iOS 7.0.4 on an iPhone 4 with the same result. As for the unit testing, I worked around it by subclassing NSOutputStream and forcing it to the desired behavior. Some feedback on the original question would still be nice though.

UPDATE 2: I have now tested it on an iPhone 4 running iOS 6.1.3, as well as on OS X 10.9. Same result as above on both, so it's not OS specific.

Comment: I'd be more than happy if it would always produce an error, but sometimes it does not give you any error back, it simply blocks the calling thread.